# Paypal express bug with country?

Tags: paypal, paypal-express

I have created my eshop and i am testing it now. I have found the following issue:
Let me explain the case:

Lets say I am a customer and I have a paypal account with my address info . My country is Greece. 
I have an onepage checkout plugin with geoip. Lets say i am in France now and i place an order so as to be shipped to Greece. I buy a product and i am redirected to my onepage checkout screen. Geo ip has detected and set the country to France. I dont want to use onepage fields so i click paypal express button in that screen and i am redirected to paypal.
When i login and click continue i am redirected from paypal to the eshop, to the review details page. There, the country is set to France and not Greece which is the country that my paypal account has. All other fields are correctly retrieved by paypal.
This means that magento ignores paypal country and overwrites it with magento's selected country.

Can it be fixed?

(i ve tried also to use core magento checkout, and i inserted country and other info to shipping address fields, i clicked next(so as to post them to server) and then i clicked paypal express button. again review ignored paypal data.)

Comment: You should check what the redirect request has as data. If the information of country is included, you can add it for sure.